# How to run a stored procedure in EF/VB.net without knowing the type of the queries result?

Tags: sql-server, wpf, vb.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

My application uses a SQL Server database to store its data. The database administrator can create any queries in this database in the form of stored procedures with parameters.

These stored procedures in turn can be executed by my application. So, the users of my application can use these stored procedures without coming into direct contact with them. They enter the required parameters in my application, press a button, whereupon the query is executed (Entity Framework; `Database.SqlQuery`).

But all my application knows about these stored procedures is their name and their parameters.

The problem now is that I don't have a model for returning the data, since I don't even know what data columns the database administrator uses in his `SELECT FROM` statement.

`Database.SqlQuery(Of Object)` does not contain any data columns.

How can I display the data columns from a stored procedure in a grid, for example, without knowing the data columns themselves?

EDIT: it is a WPF application.

Comment: You should at least tell us what is it - a winform or webform application

Comment: I have a similar WebForms application I believe (although it's in C#). Basically, on the front end (Run.aspx) I have a `GridView` called `selectResults` and a data source called `selectDS`. Then in the code behind, I run the query, and run the code `selectResults.DataSource = selectDS`, and `selectResults.DataBind()`. Of course, this code is in C# so it's not directly applicable to your situation, but the short answer is make a GridView and a DataSource on the page, and then on button click bind the query to the data source, and bind the data source to the GridView.

Comment: Serge - sorry. It is a WPF application.

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. If it's about WPF than add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Use a dataset and a table adapter, this is not applicable for EF Core

Comment: Dapper is the tool for this. It returns a dynamic object that implements IDictionary which a grid should be able to handle.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, this situation isn't really ideal for EF, unless you're going to strike a deal with the DBA that they will always only return columns of a particular name and type (or some small variations) then you cannot effectively map them to objects, which have fixed properties. If you regard columns as properties, and properties as intrinsic to a kind of object then clearly these are different every day objects:

```
Name                    = "John"
Age                     = 23
Weight                  = 220
SocialSecurityNumber    = "ABC123"
```

And

```
Manufacturer        = "Ford"
Model               = "Mustang"
EngineSize          = "6.7"
VIN                 = "1234FM"
```

Can you guess what they are just by looking at the props (not the values)?

Sure, we could say "let's map them generically", we'll have one object and we'll mangle the properties into it

```
{
  Maker          = "Mom & Pop",
  Model          = "John",
  GovtIdentifier = "ABC123",
  Weight         = 220
},
{
  Maker          = "Ford",
  Model          = "Mustang",
  GovtIdentifier = "1234FM",
  Weight         = 4400
},
```

..but there isn't a really good way to refer to everything (EngineSize?), and you have to keep going adding more and more props, more and more of which will be null, if you can't reuse them..

All in, not EF's bag. EF wants entities, and every time you add one, thats a recompile and rerelease..

---

If the results will be wide ranging, and massively different in name/type from one query to the next, use a more dynamic container like a DataTable:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Using da as New SqlDataAdapter("some_proc_name", "some connection string here")
   da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", "whatever") 
   da.Fill(dt);
End Using
myDataGrid.DataContext = dt
```

..so you assign it as the datacontext of a grid that autogenerates columns:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Note: the usual "addwithvalue is evil" advice doesn't really apply to sprocs